# Admob and Google Play Services Crash

Tags: android, admob

I am facing a real Problem right now. I just want to display Admob Banner Ads in my Application, I am using android play services version '6171000'

I have declared this in my manifest inside the application tag

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But when I am starting th App i get this error Log: Does Admob really need this old version of google play services?

```
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 6171000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ah.a(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.aM(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.a(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at admanager.v5.AdMobBannerLoader.load(AdMobBannerLoader.java:38)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at admanager.v5.AdMobBannerLoader.load(AdMobBannerLoader.java:1)
12-03 09:11:17.559: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at admanager.v5.base.implementation.BaseAdManager$1.onResponse(BaseAdManager.java:236)
```

Comment: I only know the error the other way around. That was, when I was having an old version of the service lib! what is your minSDK?

Comment: Thanks fixed it, the jar was another version as the value was saved in the xml